# Create a world-readable file

Tags: android

I would like to create a file in Android, which could be accessed by all the applications, even if there is no external storage, but I don't know where can I create this file (in which folder) in the internal storage.
Can you help me ?
(Sorry for my langage, I'm french ^^)

Comment: Check the docs? https://developer.android.com/training/building-content-sharing.html (It's not in french, sorry).

Comment: The Context class has all those access level flags defined.

Comment: Thanks !!
I will try to read this, I hope this will help me :-)